# Using $_GET variables with wordpress pretty permalink structure

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a link in a page that I want to go to the page named buy-item.php and add onto that `?name=$image_name`.

The issue is though that my permalink structure is just `my_wordpress_site.com/buy-item/`, so when I try to code my href as

`<a href="my_wordpress_site.com/buy-item/?name=$image_name">buy now</a>`

or as

`<a href="my_wordpress_site.com/buy-item?name=$image_name">buy now</a>` I get a page not found error.

How can I do this?

Comment: Try changing the ? to an &. The buy-item may be being processed by WP as a variable (depending on how their htaccess is set up to rewrite the virtual directories)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sorted it, you can't have name as a parameter, wordpress already uses that, which is why it wasn't working.

Comment: good to know! thats always the problem with open source, you have to somehow live and breath the documentation...

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix : rename and move buy-item.php to buy-item/index.php

Heavy fix : RewriteRule ^/buy-item/(.*)$ buy-item.php$1 [QSA,L]

Hope this helps !

Comment: I'm not sure how to use it to be honest, I have found this page http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule which is to do with rewrite rules, but I'm not sure quite sure what I'm doing